# Python. Получить значение из кавычек

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида:

> 'текст1', 'текст2', 'текст3', 'текст4', 'текст5'

как получить значение текст4?

Comment: почему у вас строка, это несколько строк? перефразируйте вопрос..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

text = "'текст1', 'текст2', 'текст3', 'текст4', 'текст5'"

m = re.search("'.+?', '.+?', '.+?', '(.+?)', '.+?'", text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
# текст4

m = re.findall("'(.+?)'", text)
if m:
    print(m[3])
# текст4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_1 = 'текст1', 'текст2', 'текст3', 'текст4', 'текст5'

list(str_1)[3]

# 'текст4'
```